# How do I integrate IBM Integration Bus v9.0.0.8 with Bamboo and BitBucket for CI

Tags: ant, websphere, bitbucket, versioning, esb

Our Enterprise Service Broker team is currently considering moving to the Atlasian Stack as this is a company wide standard and will assist with our Continuous Integration (CI) and continuous Development (CD).

We would like to automate our builds as well as deployments and use Bamboo (Bamboo Agent) to create our artifacts and execute our scrips that we have chosen to write in ANT.

We are currently using Rational Team Concert (RTC - Version control tool) and would like to port to BitBucket so that we can use Bamboo. Is there someone that can guide us in this process, what are the steps we need to take.

I have searched the IBM documentation and they only support bamboo on version 10.2.1410 of the IBM development toolkit which we are not yet making use of as we will not be able to upgrade yet.

Ref: https://docops.ca.com/ca-release-automation/integrations/en/optional-action-packs/ibm-integration-bus-advanced

Are there any best-practices for doing so? Tutorials maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect an RTC to a Git repository. The documentation currently states that it support GitLab and GitHub Enterprise, but nothing about BitBucket.Take a look at this part of the documentation. I think however, you could connect to BitBucket, but jsut treat it like a GitLab repo. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.4/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html